# document generation software that automatically saves on generation

Tags: ms-word, pdf-generation, document

I essentially need some document generation software that will create my documents based on predefined questions and answers. This is fine, they all do that.

However, I need the software to act in a specific way. 
When I have answered all the questions/entered all the data, I then need to press "go" or "generate" or whatever, then instead of the generated file just appearing, I need it to just save to a specific directory.

This specific directory is a "watched" folder on the document management system which it will then automatically catagorise and sort.

Any recommendations?

Hotdocs is good, but you still have to manually save the document once it is generated (even though in their promo vid it shows workflows that save automatically)

Comment: Is it an option to programm the app that does the generation and saving yourself? You could code something for example with C# and OpenXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trailing many different pieces of popular software for this purpose, none provided the solution I require.
Although almost all of the software companies promised automation, seamless integration and cooperation with document management systems. None actually delivered that.

The solution was an Excel User form linked to Word templates.

With the use of VBA I can open, update, and save these documents at a specified location. All from Excel ad based on the users input.